# Accessing $index of outer v-repeat directive in inner v-repeat directive

Tags: html-table, vue.js

Here is the simplified example of data I am working with. `fruits:['apple','orange','banana']` which is dynamic. The number and types of fruits are not same always.

I have another  list `seasons:['summer','winter']` which is also dynamic. The number and type of seasons are also not same always.

I need to generate a table. The table has one row for each of the fruit. There will be one column for each season in the table.

For the values of seasons columns I have another object like this:

```
available: {
  summer: ['yes', 'no', 'yes'],
  winter: ['yes', 'no', 'no']
}
```

After the table is generated it would look like this:

```
Fruits   Summer Winter
Apple    yes    yes
orange   no     no
Banana   yes    no
```

To render this in vue I am using this:

```
<tr v-repeat="fruit: fruits">
    <td v-text="fruit"></td>
    <td v-repeat="season: seasons" v-text="available[season][$index]"></td>
</tr>
```

The problem here is `$index` gives the index of `seasons` object. But I need to access the index of `fruits` object.

How can I access `index` of `fruits` object inside inner `v-repeat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to access the fruit `$index` inside the inner `v-repeat`, but you could try something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Fruits</th>
    <th>Summer</th> 
    <th>Winter</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-repeat="fruit: fruits">
    <td v-text="fruit"></td>
    <td v-repeat="season: seasons" v-text="isAvailable(fruit, season)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and

```
data: {
    fruits: [
        'apple', 'orange', 'banana'
    ],
    seasons: [
        'summer', 'winter'
    ],
    available: {
        summer: ['yes', 'no', 'yes'],
        winter: ['yes', 'no', 'no']
    }
},

methods: {
    isAvailable: function (fruit, season) {
        var fruitIndex = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit)
        return this.available[season][fruitIndex]
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/pespantelis/pen/BozNWm

Comment: I tried sending arguments to functions '"isAvailable(fruit, season)"' but it didn't work.